# Как открыть порт 3128 для инстанса в GCP?

Tags: google-cloud

На GCP в web-интерфейсе (Сеть VPC-Правила брандмауэра) я добавил 2 правила с приоритетом 1000:

squid-1 для 'Входящий трафик' c 'Диапазоны IP-адресов: 0.0.0.0/0' и портом 'tcp:3128'
и
squid-2 для 'Исходящий трафик' c 'Диапазоны IP-адресов: 0.0.0.0/0' и портом 'tcp:3128'. Для обоих правил указана сеть 'default'.

Внутри инстанса с Ubuntu отключен ufw и нет активных правил iptables. Но все равно при сканировании снаружи порта 3128 не видно.

Comment: при этом приоритет для squid-1 b squid-2 указан 999, т.е. значение с большим приоритетом, чем дефолтный 1000, но все равно снаружи невидно порт 3128.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решилась после указания в правилах firewall: Targets - 'All instances in the network'.